# Entering a search query and then scraping the website that results from it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve: A user needs to look up a series of federal regulations and extract certain data from the regulation. I'm using Selenium to create an app that will do the following:

1. Ask the user to enter the regulation they want to search up.
2. The app will then pull up the website, enter the user input into the search bar and then click on submit.
3. The app will then scrape the resulting web page for certain types of data and export it to a csv file.

I can do numbers 1 and 2 above. I also can scrape the web page once it comes up. The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to save the contents of the new webpage that comes up through the search query into a new variable so that I can work with the data and scrape it.

Briefly, how the website works is that when you search for a regulation in the search bar, it doesn't load the results dynamically in the same webpage. It pulls up a completely new webpage that contains the text of the regulation. Can anyone give me some guidance on this?

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

cfr = input("Enter the title of your desired Code of Federal Regulations: ")

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://ecfr.gov"
browser.get(url)

text_area = browser.find_element(By.ID,"suggestion_query")

#clicks on the search box on the website. Sends the data in "cfr" into the search box. Submits data.
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "suggestions"))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "suggestion_query"))).send_keys(cfr)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "suggestion_query"))).submit()
```

The browser variable is set to the ecfr home page. So even though I'm successful at having the python app take the user input and pull up a new webpage by entering it as a search term, I can't scrape the new webpage because I don't know how to pull that new url and set it as a new variable so that I can work with the contents in it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need all of that code? You simply can add the search query as a parameter in the URL and access the search results directly. For instance, you can use the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) extension to Selenium to get and click the elements. Something like this:

```py
from browserist import Browser

search_query = input("Enter search query: ")

browser = Browser()
browser.open.url(f"https://www.ecfr.gov/search?flag=invalid_reference&search%5Bquery%5D={search_query}")

# Scrape the search results...
```

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist`.

Notes:

- The `input("Enter search query: ")` part prompts the user for keywords in the terminal.
- [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) doesn't need explicit conditions like `WebDriverWait`, `expected_conditions` or `element_to_be_clickable` – it's already built in so you don't have to worry about it. Instead, [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) awaits an element to be fully loaded before it interacts with it. More on this concept [here](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/#difference-from-selenium).

Here's what I get when I enter `test` as search query. I hope this is helpful. Let me know if you have questions?

[image: Browserist web scraper in action]